# If $f,g:T\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous then so is $f+g$.

Tags: general-topology

I have a lemma in my textbook and I would like to clarify if I understand it correctly:

Lemma 1 (We will use it for the main lemma):

Suppose that $f:(T_1,\mathcal{T}_1)\to(T_2,\mathcal{T}_2)$, and that $\mathcal{B}$ is a sub-basis for the topology $\mathcal{T}_2$. Then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f_{-1}(B)$ is open in $T_1$ for every $B\in \mathcal{B}$

Main Lemma:

If $f,g:T\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous then so is $f+g$.

Proof:

We note that the intervals $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$ (for every $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$) are a sub-basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

So is is enough to show that $(f+g)^{-1}(a,\infty)$ and $(f+g)^{-1}(-\infty,b)$ are open in $T$, using lemma 1. We have $$f(x)+g(x)>a \Leftrightarrow f(x)>a-gx \Leftrightarrow f(x)>r \text{ and } r>a-g(x) \text{ for some r } \Leftrightarrow f(x)>r \text{ and } g(x) > a-r \text{ for some r }$$

It follows that $$\{x: f(x)+g(x)>a\}=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}}\{x:f(x)>r\}\cap \{x:g(x)>a-r\}$$

I would just like to clarify that the sets $\{x:f(x)>r\}\cap \{x:g(x)>a-r\}$ are open for the following reasoning:

$\{x: f(x)>r\}$ is open since $x\in U$ for some $U\in T$ which satisfies $f(x)\in (r,\infty)$ (which is open) and since $f$ is continuous $U=f^{-1}(r,\infty)$ is open. Same for the set with $g(x)$.

Comment: Seems right to me. Maybe you can skip the whole argument $f(x)+g(x)>a \Leftrightarrow ...$ part looks unnecessary. Also your reason about why these sets are open seems again right to me. You can finish the proof (probably as you know) by saying arbitrary union of open sets are open.

Comment: It suffices to show that $+: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous. The rest we argue by composing

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. It's good to also show that $(f,g):T\to\mathbb{R}^2, (f,g)(x)=(f(x), g(x))$ is continuous. Then it follows from the composition of continuous functions being continuous that $+ \circ (f,g): T\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @md2perpe that fact is for free from the universal property for the product topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. Has the universal property been shown in the textbook that the OP is using? If so, it can be used. Otherwise it must be shown. And showing the continuity of $(f,g)$ can be a good exercise.